# Google Chrome chrome.sidePanel API Issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on making a chrome web extension that allows user to right click on highlighted text, choose the option in the context menu, and it opens a chrome side panel that shows fact checking information on the highlighted text.

I have the following in the content.js file:

```
function setupContextMenu() {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'define-word',
    title: 'RabbitHole',
    contexts: ['selection']
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  setupContextMenu();
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((data, tab) => {
  if (data.menuItemId === 'define-word') {
    // Capture the selected text
    const selectedText = data.selectionText;

    // Send the selected text to your background script
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      name: 'selected-text',
      data: selectedText
    });

    // Open the side panel using chrome.sidePanel.open()
    chrome.sidePanel.open({ tabId: tab.id });
  }
});
```

Currently the side panel is opening after the contextual menu option is clicked, however the user then has to right click the highlighted text again in order for it to display in the side panel.

Is there a way to have the side panel automatically display the highlighted text once the side panel is opened?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a listener for `selectionchange` even in the content script.